# Mathematical Expression

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to display the following in my thesis document:
(1/7) ≤ X < (6/7)

I tried using the command: `$\frac{1}{7}$ \leq $X < $\frac{6}{7}$`

But I keep getting error messages, such as "missing $ inserted" appointing to the part *$\frac{1}{7}$ \leq*.

Though it does print out what I want, but it still seems to be wrong somehow. And there is some white space missing between ≤ and X.

Neither
**$** **[** $\frac{1}{7}$ **]** \leq $X

nor
**$** **(** $\frac{1}{7}$ **)** \leq $X

nor
**$** **{** $\frac{1}{7}$ **}** \leq $X

nor
**$** $\frac{1}{7}$ \leq $X

were correct.

Can somebody please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove all the `$`  except one at the start and one at the end, this is a single math expression.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You don't have use a pair of  $ $ for each part of the formula. Just use  `$\frac{1}{7} \leq X < \frac{6}{7}$`.

Comment: Thanks so much! That helped, much appreciated! :)

Comment: Rewelcome :-)..I suggest to read this link also: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: @Sebastiano Very helpful link, thank you!

Comment: As a member of Math.SE, I often see `$...$` used as a way to produce “weird” symbols. It's wrong: a whole formula should be typed between the dollar symbols.

Comment: This example somewhat reminds me of Perl or PHP, in that the `$` seems to be referring to the next thing.  Instead, @user251959, `$` starts or ends math mode (and I can't think of a reason to begin a new math mode immediately after ending a prior math mode).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `\leq` should be inside the math formula, not outside. Try this:

```
 $\frac{1}{7} \leq X < \frac{6}{7}$
```

(this worked fine when making this solution).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :)